# Is it possible to generate custom chars in Java

Tags: java

I am very new in progamming and I want to make a simple task
Is it possible to generate a custom char in Java from specific list?

For example, I want that the program would give me random char only from this chars `A H F G D` ?

Is it possible?

Comment: You can have an array containing chars, and use `Math.random()` to get a random index on this array.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Writing some code will get you there!

Comment: So... you have a set of letters, and want to randomly select one? Take a look at [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) (<-- link) and it's `nextInt` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can !!

```
static char getRandomChar(String s){//pass string "AHFGD" here
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(s.length());
    return s.charAt(index);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to achieve getting pseudorandom element from given set of `chars`. You can use `Random.nextInt()` (from `java.util` package) for that purpose.

You could think of creating an array of `char`s, and then let that methods choose an element for you.

Here is an example with the use of `Random` class:

```
char[] array = new char[] {'A', 'H', 'F', 'G', 'D', };
Random rand = new Random();
char chosenOne = array[rand.nextInt(array.length)]; // there is a pseudorandomly chosen index for array in range of 0 inclusive to 5 exclusive
```

---

**EDIT:** According to your comment (you say there that you want to randomly choose elements from set of Strings of various length (that way they are no more `char`s (as `char`s are a **single** character - '`1`' or '`0`', not '`10`'), they are `String`s then), the most effortless way to achieve that result I can think of, is to put a delimiter between these values in the String. Here is a possible implementation (I made some additional explanations in the comments to the code):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = splitToSeparateElements("A,H,F,10,G,D,1,0,2000"); // store the result of calling splitToElements() with a
                                                            // given String as argument
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // this loop is just to print more results to console
        System.out.print(array[rand.nextInt(array.length)] + " "); // print pseudorandom element of array to the console
    }
}

public static String[] splitToSeparateElements(String inputString) {
    String[] splitted = inputString.split(","); // split String to separate Strings in the place of delimiter passed as argument to .split() method
    return splitted;
}
```

Sample output:

```
D 1 A A 2000 F 10 G 10 A
```

Comment: Well , Thank you

Comment: Actually, there is one solution to get a "random" value since `Math.random` will simply create an instance of `Random` if needed and call `nextDouble` which will required a bit of math to get the `int` needed. And please, use `rand.nextInt(array.length)` if you want to keep that solution useful. (I removed mine because it was a duplicated already...)

Comment: @AxelH Thank you for giving this detailed explanation, I,wasn't aware of that. I'll edit my answer to delete that information.

Comment: This is explain in [`Math.random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%299) ;)

Comment: more question: I succesfully make this ; but what  I ask more is this
on the string I involved numbers and it is work but when I want the number 10 it separate it to random 1 or 0 how can I do it '10'.

Comment: How would your program know if in that particular case you want 10 and not 1 and 0 separately? My answer doesn't deal with String input, it deals with chars, as you asked in your question. If you want to cut String into ints or other elements, you should provide a logic, why in that particular case you want 1 and 0 to be 10 and not 1 and 0, maybe implement your own parser covering your expectations and then fill array with results that you get after parsing the input String is completed. I think it's out of the scope of your question.

Comment: You right  its out of the scope... I will training more to make that program..

Comment: @NivBooskila I edited my answer with an attempt to solve a problem of getting elements of various length from given String. Please, let me know if it solves your problem.